# flutter web dart_sdk.dart.getModuleLibraries error in console

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I started to checkout the flutter web app support. Following the tutorial [1] I encountered the following error in the browser console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.$requireLoader.getModuleLibraries = dart_sdk.dart.getModuleLibraries')

Line: 16:22
URL: http://rebalancr.net:45441/main_module.bootstrap.js
Error: {}
```

None of the functionality of the tutorial works. E.g. progress bar and welcome window.

I`m using the latest beta build

```
$ flutter --version
Flutter 1.17.0 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d3ed9ec945 (8 days ago) • 2020-04-06 14:07:34 -0700
Engine • revision c9506cb8e9
Tools • Dart 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.18.0 eea9717938)
```

Here my is my complete main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(LoginApp());

class LoginApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => LoginScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 400,
          child: Card(
            child: LoginForm(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final _firstNameTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _lastNameTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _usernameTextController = TextEditingController();

  double _formProgress = 0;

  @override
  void _showWelcomeScreen() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/welcome');
  } 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          LinearProgressIndicator(value: _formProgress),
          Text('Sign Up', style: Theme
              .of(context)
              .textTheme
              .display1), // display1 changes to headline4 in 1.16
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _firstNameTextController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'First name'),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _lastNameTextController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Last name'),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _usernameTextController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Username'),
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: _showWelcomeScreen,
            child: Text('Sign up'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Welcome!', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display3),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[1] https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab-web

I`m happy about any idea how to approach this.

Thanks!

Comment: did you get a solution?

Comment: Hi Remy, no, I did not find a solution. Back then Flutter support for Web Apps was not mature enough for me. I dropped Flutter and went with Quasar instead. Havent looked back since. https://quasar.dev/